# Expressing dynamic polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism, visual-studio-2019

Based on the animals danger rating that is inputted by the user, the `calculate_insurance` method will select the correct case and run the calculation to determine the cost of the animals insurance.
The danger rating is set in the parent class
The insurance calculation is done in the 2 child classes with **dynamic polymorphism** by overriding the parent class. Whats the best way of solving this? explanation with your code would be greatly appreciated

Base class -

```
public abstract class Animal
{
        protected int danger_rating = 0;

          //get danger rating from user (1-5)
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the animals danger rating? \nSelect a number between 1 - 5: "); //Prompt user to type in animals danger rating
            string input = Console.ReadLine(); //reads string input 

            if (int.TryParse(input, out danger_rating)) //convert user string input to int danger_rating
            {
                if (danger_rating == 1) //loop until danger_rating is between 1 and 5
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (danger_rating == 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (danger_rating == 3)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (danger_rating == 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (danger_rating == 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number. \nNumber must be between 1 - 5");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a number");
            }

        public virtual double calculate_insurance(int danger_rating)
        {
            return 0;
        } 
}
```

Mammal class -

```
public class Mammal : Animal //Derived class
{
        public virtual double calculate_insurance(int danger_rating)
        {
            int ins_base = 5000; //base for mammals
            
            double Insurance; //this will contain the output

            //Select case based on danger rating 1 - 5
            switch (danger_rating)
            {
                case 1:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 10) * 0.02;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 20) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 30) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 40) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 5:

                    Insurance = (ins_base * 50) * 0.10;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid danger rating");
                    break;

            } //end of switch

            return base.calculate_insurance(danger_rating);

        }
}
```

Reptile class -

```
public class Reptile : Animal //Derived class
{
        public virtual double calculate_insurance(int danger_rating)
        {
            int ins_base = 1000; //base for reptiles
            
            double Insurance; //this will contain the output

            //Select case based on danger rating 1 - 5
            switch (danger_rating)
            {
                case 1:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 10) * 0.02;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 20) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 30) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 40) * 0.05;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    Insurance = (ins_base * 50) * 0.10;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid danger rating");
                    break;

            } //end of switch

            return base.calculate_insurance(danger_rating);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure there is a problem to "solve", other than a syntax error in the base class of a while loop floating round at method level and some wonkiness where you calculate some insurance value for a derived type but then return the base type's insurance calc (which is 0).

Your `calculate_insurance` methods in Mammal and Reptile should be declared to `override` the base method, and should end with `return Insurance` (note; it should be called `insurance`; we do not name local variables in PascalCase) not returning the result of calling the base..

If you're then asking how to use what you have created. The idea behind polymorphism of this nature is that you can have a variable of the base type and not know or care what actual type is stored inside it, because you're only using functionality the base type claims exists

```
Animal a = new Mammal();
a.calculate_insurance(1);  //returns 1000, the rating for a Mammal of type 1

Animal b = new Reptile();
b.calculate_insurance(1);  //returns 200, the rating for a Reptile of type 1
```

Comment: Would i declare both `public virtual double calculate_insurance` methods to be displayed as `public override double calculate_insurance` ?
Once i `return insurance` that should remove the "wonkiness" and display the result of one of the equations in my switch case?

Comment: Yes; the base class method is `virtual` because it does have an implementation (perhaps it shouldn't, and it should instead be marked `abstract`) and then the derived class methods override it with new implementations. By being present on the base class it effectively promises that all Animals will have this method, even though it does different things in each Class that derives from Animal, the compiler can know that something will happen and a double will be returned for an integer passed in, when it is called on any kind of animal.

Comment: You can have an array of Animal with 100 different kinds of animal inside it all doing different things to calculate the insurance premium and you can add them all up in the same way to know the total without caring what animal they are. That is the wonder of polymorphism;)

Comment: Thank you so much for everything, your advice has been a big help and the program is running smoothly along with a better understanding of the topic

Comment: You're most welcome!